# Позиционирование

Tags: html5, css3, layout, position

Подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать эти черные квадраты, не используя `position: absolute` для белых блоков?
[image: layout]

Comment: Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него конкретную проблему, которая возникла у вас в процессе решения данной задачи. В противном случае, вопрос может быть закрыт проверяющими. Чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: С помощью `margin-top: -n px` можно такое сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно абсолют задавать черному а не белому квадрату.
[Вот так](https://jsfiddle.net/odinokun/htpycz44/) например.

```
<div class=grey>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>


.grey {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.black {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо!!!